# How i Can make my Sencha app compatible with intrnet explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs, internet-explorer-8, extjs4, sencha-touch

I Have design a sencha app that is running fine enough on chrome and mozilla.
but it's not working with ie8 and i have to test it on ie8 also for my client.
it's working fine on higher version of ie like ie9 and ie10
is there anyone who can help me to make it compatible with ie8.

Comment: Ext JS is IE8 (all the way back to IE6, I think) compatible... whereas Sencha Touch is *not*. You'll have to clarify what version of which framework you're using, as well as describe what specifically is "not working".

Comment: In addition to what @arthurakay said you should provide the exact extjs version you're using and what you've tried so far. Please check if the IE debug console using the dev (or debug) version of the library (ext-dev.js) provides some useful information. Also tell us if problems occur on development and/or built (compiled/minified) versions of your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sticking strictly to using ExtJS code? A common issue that might be preventing your application from loading might be the usage of console.log()s. Another thing you'll want to check for is making sure you don't have any trailing commas, or missing semicolons. If that fails, chances are you are using some native JavaScript or some other library that isn't compatible with IE8.